# Mocha Express Coffee should.equal not working

Tags: coffeescript, express, mocha.js

I am following a [tutorial](http://blog.james-carr.org/2012/01/16/blog-rolling-with-mongodb-node-js-and-coffeescript/#comment-348560). While I run

```
require "should"

describe "feature", ->
   it "should add two numbers", ->
    (2+2).should.equal 4
```

And i run

```
mocha routes-test.coffee --compilers coffee:coffee-script
```

I get following errors

```
 1) feature should add two numbers:
 AssertionError: expected {} to be true
  at Object.true (/home/../../coffeepress/node_modules/should/lib/should.js:251:10)
  at Context.<anonymous> (/home/../../coffeepress/test/routes-test.coffee:7:28)
  at Test.Runnable.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:184:32)
  at Runner.runTest (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:300:10)
  at Runner.runTests.next (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:346:12)
  at next (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:228:14)
  at Runner.hooks (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:237:7)
  at next (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:185:23)
  at Runner.hook (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:205:5)
  at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

What is going on here? I installed should.js ( npm install should) and mocha. Is there some syntax mistake or some setting mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely a mismatch between your node version and the versions of mocha and should that you used. If you used the `package.json` file from that tutorial exactly you would have loaded mocha 0.10.0 and should 0.5.1. When I tried the same thing with a current version of node (v0.8.1) I saw the following warnings when doing `npm install`:

```
npm WARN engine mocha@0.10.0: wanted: {"node":">= 0.4.x < 0.7.0"} (current: {"node":"0.8.1","npm":"1.1.34"})
npm WARN engine commander@0.5.1: wanted: {"node":">= 0.4.x < 0.7.0"} (current: {"node":"0.8.1","npm":"1.1.34"})
```

And then when I run mocha against the example test you've provided I get the same error.

Simply changing the mocha and should versions in my `package.json` to be

```
"mocha": ">=0.10.0",
"should": ">=0.5.1"
```

then running `npm update` fixed the problem and the test ran fine. You can also set those versions to `"latest"` or the current versions of those packages if you'd like to lock them down (`"1.3.0"` and `"0.6.3"` respectively at the time I write this).

Comment: thanx a lot. I knew ( had a feeling) it had to do something with the versions.